# Why operator () [] -> = must be non-static member?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are some operators in C++ only allowed to be overloaded as member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132600/why-are-some-operators-in-c-only-allowed-to-be-overloaded-as-member-functions)

Why operator () [] -> = must be non-static member? Why it can't be friend?

Comment: Is there any operator that can be a static member?

Comment: @jleedev: Yes, +, -, /, *... you get it.

Comment: @jleedev: It's common to make insertion and extraction operators that aren't members at all, much less static members, of the class they're defined with.  Other operators can do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have to call it on an instance of a class.  Take for example the -> operator.  How would you propose getting a pointer to the class itself?  It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: What about non-member functions?

Comment: Well it isn't said that `->` has to return the pointer to the class it is called on. It could return any pointer. What do you mean with “ pointers point to heap allocated memory”? Pointers can point to statically allocated memory too. As said in my comment that’s just a design decision.

Answer (score 1):

Because it has to be non-static. Simple design decision. Probably because C++ doesn't have the concept of class objects.

Comment: What do you mean C++ doesn't have the concept of class objects? It has classes, it has objects, and you can put objects inside other classes... am I missing something here?

Comment: Classes aren't objects themselves. They don't really exist. Try to assign a class to something.